# openssl and TLS custom certs

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I am following this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/encrypt-data-in-transit-using-a-tls-custom-certificate-provider-with-amazon-emr/):
Essentially for the organizations which has very strict security requirements would like EMR nodes to communicate to each other following TLS custom certificate provider.

Certs - I am more of a beginner/intermediate level. Can follow the instructions and modify it with some logic but definitely not an expert.

Regarding this command

```
   openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout inter-nodes.key -out inter-nodes.crt -days 365 -subj "/C=US/ST=MA/L=Boston/O=EMR/OU=EMR/CN=*.ec2.internal" -nodes
```

I cannot use the self signed certificates but have to use the certificates issued by CA for our organization which is root cert and another cert. Organization_Corp_Root_CA.cer and Organization_Corp_Issuing_CA.cer.

How i can change the above command to generate inter-nodes.key and inter-nodes.crt in my situation?
I can substitute -subj "/C=US/ST=MA/L=Boston/O=EMR/OU=EMR/CN=*.ec2.internal" with -subj "/O=EMR/OU=EMR/CN=*.ec2.internal" or only this -subj "/O=EMR/OU=EMR/CN=*.ec2.internal"

and **substitute for req**
 -in arg        input file with one of the certs(I am assuming)
 -key file      use the private key contained in file

but it's not working and I am getting all kind of errors.

Also -days 365 can be something else based on security requirements.

Any help?

Comment: " I know .cer is for Windows platform and .crt for non windows." No. Start by removing this false assumption that filenames (or extensions) matter. They do not. You can name your certificate foobar.acme42 on disk and it will work EXACTLY as if using any other name. Names are just for humans, to identify more easily what is in the file, computers do not care on the name, just the content.

Comment: `openssl req` is to generate certificate requests (CSR) that you hand to CAs so that they generate the certificate, or to create self signed certificates, which is the form you are using. But then you are speaking about other certificates, and the whole question is not clear. More than that is it probably offtopic here as not related to programming.